# Can **Kronecker product** explained operators in matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product

I'm going to create matrix $A_{n\times kn}$ for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
$$A=\underbrace{[I_{n\times n},I_{n\times n},\dots,I_{n\times n}]}_{k\text{ times}}$$
Complete Answer to my question to have a good Matlab code given in comments by @Wauzl and in math with @A.P.
But a new question come up here. Is there any logical proof to explain we can't made **Kronecker product** with normal and point wise product in matrices.

Comment: You'd be better off asking things like this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab).

Comment: Also, use `repmat(eye(n),1,k)`.

Comment: @Wauzl Would you mind posting that as an answer, please?

Comment: @A.P. Command that **Wauzl** provide is an answer in **stackoverflow**. Not a mathematic approach.(First version of my question was not mathematical too.)

Comment: You can easily write it as a [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product): $$\underbrace{[1,\dotsc,1]}_{k \text{ times}} \otimes I_{n \times n}.$$ If you plan on using it in your code, though, `repmat` is likely more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the best way to build that matrix in MATLAB is with the code snippet proposed by Wauzl

```
A = repmat(eye(n), 1, k)
```

You could also try with the [`kron`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html?searchHighlight=kronecker%20product) function

```
A = kron(ones(1,k), eye(n))
```

but I don't think this can be more efficient than `repmat`. I don't currently have access to MATLAB, though, so I can't test this.

---

As I mentioned in my comment above, mathematically you can easily define
$$
A = \underbrace{[I_{n\times n},\dots,I_{n\times n}]}_{k \text{ times}}
$$
as a [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)
$$
\underbrace{[1,\dotsc,1]}_{k \text{ times}} \otimes I_{n \times n}.
$$

---

Note that there is no matrix that can be used to write $B \otimes \, -$ (for a fixed $h \times k$ matrix $B$) as a usual matrix product or, in other words, there is no matrix $C$ such that
$$
B \otimes \, - = C \, -
\quad \text{or} \quad
B \otimes \, - = - \, C
$$
This is simply because $B \otimes \, -$ is defined for every possible matrix while, say, $C \, -$ is defined only for matrices with the same number of rows as the number of columns of $C$.

"But!", you may say, "What if I restrict $B \otimes \, -$ to matrices of a given size, say $n \times n$?"

Glad you asked! It still isn't possible unless $h = 1$ or $k = 1$. Indeed, suppose that, say, $B \otimes \, - = C \, -$ for some $x \times y$ matrix $C$. Now observe that if $M$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then the size of $B \otimes M$ is $hn \times kn$. On the other hand $CM$ (which is defined only if $y = n$) has size $x \times n$. Similarly for $B \otimes \, - = - \, C$.

So... suppose that, say, $B = [b_1,\dotsc,b_k]$ is a $1 \times k$ vector. Then it is easy to see that $B \otimes \, - = - \, C$ with
$$
C = \left[ b_1 I_{n \times n} \dotsb b_k I_{n \times n} \right].
$$
On the other hand, we can't really use this to write $A$ as a product of "more elementary" matrices, because for $B = [1,\dotsc,1]$ we have $C = A$.